# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getpwnam'

Tags: python-3.x, passwords, pycharm, psutil

I want to use the following code to change the owner of files:

```
import os

from getpwnam import pwd
from getgrnam import grp

uid = getpwnam('edamame')[2]
gid = grp.getgrnam('staff')[2]
os.chown('/Users/edamame/workspace/git/chinese_nlp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py', uid, gid)
```

But the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/chinese_nlp/chinese_segmenter1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from getpwnam import pwd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getpwnam'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using Python 3.7 virtual env in PyCharm. I couldn't find the module called getpwnam to install. Which package should I install? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You got the imports a bit backwards, I know, it happens :) Try this ([`pwd`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pwd.html) and [`grp`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/grp.html) are just standard Python library modules):

```
>>> from pwd import getpwnam
>>> getpwnam('root')[2]
0
>>> from grp import getgrnam
>>> getgrnam('root')[2]
0
```